# Control + s not working even though it's enabled on my Visual studio code

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

[image]

**As you can see here, my shortcut key for save is already enabled, i tried changing it and then changing it back but nothing seems to be working, it's still not working when i press the key combination, please help this is so frustrating**

I also looked on few of the answers on stack overflow but they are not working for me

Comment: It's because of some plugin you have used. Do you remember to download any plugins?

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_troubleshooting-keybindings